# the result is adding a number in morris.js chart

Tags: javascript, php

i have a problem in the result it add's '19' before the xkeys

this is a photo
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-oUEl-TORxUI/XCTp1gEJA5I/AAAAAAAACNE/ipGtuyFnMX4P4zQyJcwVGIrYt7ZAkrepQCLcBGAs/s1600/Sans%2Btitre.png

[image]

```
        $dates =  array($datestatics7[0], $datestatics6[0], $datestatics5[0], $datestatics4[0], $datestatics3[0], $datestatics2[0], $datestatics1[0]) ;
        $datess =  array($date66, $date55, $date44, $date33, $date22, $date11, $date00) ;




        $chart_data = '';
        $datesz = '';

        foreach($dates as $index => $dates2 )
        {
         $chart_data .= "{ day:'".$datess[$index]."', balance:'".$dates2."'}, ";
        }
        $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
<script>
Morris.Line({
 element : 'chart',
 data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
 xkey:['day'],
 ykeys:['balance'],
 labels:['balance'],
 hideHover:'auto',
 stacked:true
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is your issue but I'd use `rtrim` rather than `substr($chart_data, 0, -2);`. Can you provide a sample of what your output is? I'd also restructure your array so you could just call `json_encode` https://3v4l.org/HVDbh.

Comment: Because it's not in a recognized format, so it's converting it to a year in the 1900s. `A string containing the name of the attribute that contains date (X) values. 
Timestamps are accepted in the form of millisecond timestamps (as returned by Date.getTime() or as strings`.  https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html